# Set browser cookie of xyz.com via abc.com's javascript by calling the xyz.com's API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, passport.js

I have the scenario where I have a domain e.g. abc.com in which I have stored credentials to login to xyz.com. What I want is to login to xyz.com on click abc.com link with the stored credentials. I am calling API of xyz.com from abc.com via javascript. The xyz.com has the API running on express(nodejs). What I want to do is to set the browser cookie for xyz.com by calling its API from abc.com's javascript code.

In the xyz.com API, I have this :

```
 function doAuthentication() {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    passport.authenticate('password-grant', {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      session: false
    })(req, res, next);
  }
}

function sendToken(req, res, next) {
  var data = {
    token: auth.signToken(req.user._id, req.user._password, req.user.sessionTimeout)
  };
  // res.cookie('token', data.token, {
  //   domain: 'localhost',
  //   path: '/'
  // });
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie': 'token='+data.token,
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
  // res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

router.post('/login', doAuthentication(), sendToken, function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(new Error('Error occurred in login in process').stack);
  console.log(err);
  return res.send(403, err);
});
```

Please help me out this.

Comment: Set `withCredentials` property of the request object to `true`

Comment: @charlietfl where would be the setting at client side of nodejs server side ?

Comment: You said the request is ajax...so request object is in client. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: @charlietfl this really helped. Thanks :) Please add this to answer so I could mark this as answer.